# Accessing coredata `faults` makes all coredata properties NIL in viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I'm fetching data from coredata table **STUDENT** and displaying all student names in tableview with Array. and after selecting any one of the student name(**tap on tableViewCell**), it fetches full details of Student from another table and displays in next profile view controller.

Now problem is, In profile view controller I'm opening control centre of iPhone (To turn on Bluetooth/Wifi/Music etc.) and after I dismiss control centre my all variables becomes nil, even if I'm pop to previous screen (which is list of all student names), it shows blank table.

When I debug this issue, I found that my Student Array becomes Nil during pop viewcontroller. This issue only occurs when I open control centre tray while using application, otherwise it maintains all array and variables as it suppose to.

I don't know why it makes array Nil in parent view controller. I'm accessing control centre in profile viewcontroller and it reset my array in parent view controller.

I don't know why this is happening ? Is there any way to resolve it ? After opening control centre, Do I need to set all variables again ? Is there any state maintain problem or something ? Is there any coredata related problem ?

Error is looks like this :

```
5 elements
      - 0 : <Student: 0x17468c670> (entity: Challenge; id: 0xd0000000665c0006 <x-coredata://C8F37C3F-3153-4EA5-9914-0CEBEB5731E4/Challenge/p6551> ; data: <fault>)
      - 1 : <Student: 0x17488b4f0> (entity: Challenge; id: 0xd000000066600006 <x-coredata://C8F37C3F-3153-4EA5-9914-0CEBEB5731E4/Challenge/p6552> ; data: <fault>)
      - 2 : <Student: 0x174887a80> (entity: Challenge; id: 0xd000000066640006 <x-coredata://C8F37C3F-3153-4EA5-9914-0CEBEB5731E4/Challenge/p6553> ; data: <fault>)
      - 3 : <Student: 0x17488b270> (entity: Challenge; id: 0xd000000066680006 <x-coredata://C8F37C3F-3153-4EA5-9914-0CEBEB5731E4/Challenge/p6554> ; data: <fault>)
      - 4 : <Student: 0x1746823f0> (entity: Challenge; id: 0xd0000000666c0006 <x-coredata://C8F37C3F-3153-4EA5-9914-0CEBEB5731E4/Challenge/p6555> ; data: <fault>)
```

Here `data` is having `<fault>`, Array is contains 5 object but when I try to access that object property, they are Nil. It seems coredata object becomes blank.

I'm working in swift 3.0, Xcode 8. iOS 10.2. Looking for help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in which I moved **coredata object** into **class object**. and now it maintains data automatically  in class object, as it's default behaviour in iOS.
Thanks for suggestion everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Fault is a coredata feature for manage memory usage.

There is not an error.

If you access to Student.data property, core data will fetch a request and then you will have your entire data.

Comment: If I'm trying to access `Student.name`, it gives me `nil`.
How can I access `.data` property. I think it would be `nil`?
Is there any concern with `Delete Rule` in coredata entity? I set all table relations as `nullify`.

Comment: check this post: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-a-core-data-fault--cms-25157. Hope it helps

Comment: I got the explanation you are trying to explain, but how to bind `fault` back to coredata? I also read [Apple Coredata Programming Guide] (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html). But couldn't found any solution. :(  For example, if I moving my app in background and bringing back to foreground, coredata property becomes nil (i.e. fault). Then, I'm not able to access property. `Student.name` is always nil. If I reload table, it shows blank table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you holding onto your `NSManagedObjectContext` in a property on the class or a singleton? If not, the managed object context backing the entities will get deallocated and your entities will fail to fault data back into memory. Control center is probably causing memory pressure to automatically evict the entity data.

Answer (score 0):

I handled with creating separate model class. So now I need to access only class object, not coredata property. It's not an exact solution which I was looking for but it could be the solution also. It's working perfectly.
Thanks everybody.!! :)

Comment: Hey. How exactly did you do it? Because sometimes my NSManagedObject is empty, no values on it ... and it displays the default ones making my views empty. Can you provide an example how to avoid that?

Comment: Did you ever find out what to do?